# How to link to live chat TawkTo module pop up window with Drupal 7?

Tags: navigation

I have Tawkto module installed, and I want to create link on my main menu for:

"Live Chat"

The link is:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())"> Click to Chat </a>
```

Now this works fine on static HTML pages, but when I paste it in field for main menu, it doesn't work.

I've tried:

```
 /javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())
```

And:

```
 javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())
```

How can I do this?

The site with Livechat is:

[www.vuxi.com](http://vuxi.com)

Comment: You can try implementing [theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x) hook in your theme's template.php file and replace the link for your menu. You can implement hook using `[THEME_NAME]_menu_link` function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using [Void Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/void_menu) module.

1. Download & Install [Void Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/void_menu) module.
2. Go to http://www.yoursite.com/admin/config/user-interface/void_menu
3. Set **javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())** as value for **HTML value for `<void2>`**
4. Then go to main menu configuration and set menu **Path** as **`<void2>`**

Comment: Yep, that works perfectly ;)